# Modificar el cuerpo de una función en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: python

Quería saber si sería posible de alguna forma, durante la ejecución, modificar una función.
En un principio me parece que no porque ya está compilado. Como máximo puedo obtener el objeto código `__code__` de la función o usar `inspect.getsource()` para verlo. Pero lo que me gustaría hacer es cambiar el cuerpo de una función a partir de una cadena de texto introducida a través de un intérprete de comandos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependiendo de qué quieras admitir como cadena de texto, la solución podría ser `eval()` o `exec()`.

`eval()` te permite evaluar expresiones, pero no código python arbitrario. En cambio `exec()` sí permite código arbitrario.

Considera el siguiente ejemplo:

```
def funcion_original(x):
    return 2*x

print(funcion_original(2))
# Sale 4

entrada_del_usuario = """
def funcion_usuario(x):
    return 3*x
"""

exec(entrada_del_usuario)
funcion_original = funcion_usuario

print(funcion_original(2))
# Sale 6
```

En este caso el usuario debe plegarse a lo que se espera de él, que es una definición de función llamada `funcion_usuario()`. Si quieres puedes hacer que el usuario introduzca sólo el cuerpo de la función, y concatenarle tú por delante la línea del `def` (e indentar lo que el usuario introdujo).

Ni que decir tiene que esto es **altamente peligroso**, pues el usuario en lugar de una definición de función puede introducir código python arbitrario, por ejemplo `os.remove("fichero_importante")`.